# Are Motherboards for the Acer Aspire One AOA150 Netbook Compatible with the AOA110?

Tags: motherboard, netbook, acer-aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One ZG5 AOA110-1588 netbook, and the motherboard doesn't have a port for a SATA 2.5 inch hard drive; it only supports this slow 8GB SSD type drive. Through research I've discovered that the AOA150 motherboards do have a SATA slot, and the bottom plate of these laptops have an appropriate protrusion for the drive to fit in (for example, compare [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Acer-Aspire-One-ZG5-AOA110-Base-Bottom-Case-EAZG5002-R-/180665886269?pt=US_Laptop_Housings_Touchpads&hash=item2a1086a63d) to [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/BOTTOM-PLASTIC-FOR-Acer-Aspire-One-ZG5-AOA150-1570-LAPTOP-/270899500110?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f12de544e)). The AOA110 and AOA150 models are *very* similar in appearance and specs. I've even seen tutorials that involve soldering a SATA connector onto the AOA110's motherboard, essentially creating an AOA150 motherboard (right?)

So, could I just swap out the motherboard in my netbook with the MBS0506001? (I'd post another link to the actual board but can't because of the spam prevention...) I assume I would also need to purchase and replace the bottom cover with a larger one and possibly get a hard drive caddy as well...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The AOA110 and the AOA150 use the same ZG5 motherboard, with one caveat! Acer does not solder in any connectors that won't be used. Thus the AOA110 does not have the SATA connector and the AOA150 (presumably) does not have the SSD zif connector.
The SATA port is there on the AOA110, however, as long as you either;
a) solder in your own sata connector or;
b) solder wires from sata cables

Note that you would also need to cut away some mounting posts that are in the way to accommodate the drive.

As for replacing the bottom cover and the motherboard, you would be better off just buying a full AOA150. Even new, the cost would be almost the same! (But yes, you can do it if you happen to have a spare AOA150 MoBo)

Comment: I disagree, I'm a computer tech. I have the Acer Aspire One ZG5, and mine has a SATA connector, in fact, I am running the original 160GB SATA2 HDD that came with the netbook.